# Pull in mongoose doesn't wanna work. Any suggestions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my object:

```
{
  posts: [
    {
      _id: 603dd892548e9b30201cb254,
      title: '222222222',
      content: '222222222',
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: 603df0a5996e422c6cbd05d6,
      title: 'ANdrew',
      content: 'testestetsetste',
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: 603df53790787539a8c92472,
      title: 'vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv',
      content: 'vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv',
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: 603e2abfa384381c28529c76,
      title: 'qqqqqqqqqqqqqq',
      content: 'qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq',
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: 603e2b36550cd6289caa880b,
      title: '333',
      content: '333',
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  _id: 603dd326b8c54d1ac0afea0f,
  username: 'andrew',
  mail: 'mail@gmail.com',
  __v: 5
}
```

From array "posts" I wanna delete any item I want, so I did:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, {$pull: {posts: { _id: postID}}},  function(err, obj) {
if(!err){
  res.redirect("/")
}  });
```

Page refreshes, but every note is still there. What's going on? i tried updateOne too, and object.notes.pull({_id: postID}). All without errors as well as without deletions.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qq9cHngJOkA) your expected behaviour?. Also, you are pulling `notes` but there is not any field called `notes` into your collection.

Comment: Yeah, this behavior I expected, but nothing happens. There was typo in question, I corrected this. Of course I have "posts" in code.

Comment: Try to parse `req.user.id` to ObjectId

Comment: Are the `_id` fields of in the `posts` array ObjectId?

Comment: Joe. Yes, they are. But posts first created in post collection, and after pushed in user's post array.

Comment: Type matters, if `posts._id` is ObjectId, `postID` will also need to be in order to match.

Comment: I've installed npm uniqid, used it to create postID (not _id) for every post object, used it as  params value, and it works just fine